# How to comment C function in netbeans, so documentation hint will be formatted (bold, paragraphs ...)

Tags: c++, netbeans, documentation, comments

```
/**
 * A test function
 * @param p an integer **of your choice**
 * @return 0: if zero, 1: if positive, -1: if negative
 */
int Test(int);
```

I want the documentation hint to be formatted as :

- `Of your choice` should be bold.
- `0: if zero, 1: if positive, -1: if negative` should be in 3 lines

But instead, i get :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `<b> YOUR TEXT </b>` instead of `**`.

```
 /*
 * @param p an integer <b>of your choice</b>
 *                     ^^^              ^^^^
 */
```

For multi line, you can use `<br>` or `\n` at the end of line. You can also take advantage of other HTML text formatting tags:

```
<b> - Bold 
<strong> - Important 
<i> - Italic 
<em> - Emphasized 
<small> - Small 
<sub> - Subscript 
<sup> - Superscript
```

Comment: Can you please add a link to source? Thanks